# Turn a growing 1D lattice of size $N(t)$ into a constant size lattice by change of variables

Tags: stochastic-processes, mathematical-biology

I am studying some stochastic process (a voter model for example) on a finite size lattice of 1 dimension and of size $N_t$. However $N_t$ grows at rate $\lambda$ and can be represented as follows:

\begin{equation}
N_t=N_0+ \tilde{N}_t
\end{equation}
Where $N_0$ is the initial size of the lattice and $\tilde{N}_t$ follows a Poisson process, i.e.:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}(N_t=k)=\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!} e^{-\lambda t}
\end{equation}

Although the growth process is independent from the dynamics of the studied model, it is a bit tricky to study the dynamics. I suspect it would be possible to perform some change variable from $t$ to $\tau$ such that $N(\tau)$ is now constant. Would this be possible?

Is there any classic literature on stochastic processes on growing lattices? There does not seem to be some well established key words so maybe someone knows more about it here... Thanks.